# Appropriate cast for OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier

Tags: c, macos, casting, atomic, void

In this program:

```
int x, y; 
int *old = &x;
int *new = &y;
int * volatile cur = &x;

OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(old, new, &cur);
```

I get this warning:

> Incompatible pointer passing 'int *volatile *' to parameter of type 'void *volatile *'

on XCode 4.0.1's default compiler. (Live Issues, actually.)

Now, I know that in general I can't cast int** to void** . But if I don't, I don't see any way to compare-and-swap and int* without getting the above warning. Should I just ignore the warning, assuming it's a relic from a time of non-uniform pointer sizes, or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the warning says that the compiler considers implicit conversion from pointer-to-pointer-to-int to pointer-to-pointer-to-void as dangerous. It's not as if you could not do such a conversion; the standard says a pointer can be converted to a pointer to an object of different type, as long as type alignment requirements are satisfied. But sometimes, e.g. in case of [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) being used, it can potentially lead to problems.

I believe in your case the warning can be ignored, or possibly eliminated with explicit casts:

```
bool result = OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(old, new, &(void*)cur);
```

Also, make sure you do not forget to check the return value; ignoring the fact that atomic compare-and-swap may not succeed (due to concurrent modifications) is rarely safe.